# How to find the minimun of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I was trying to solve this [question](https://www.codechef.com/problems/HORSES)
but codechef.com says the answer is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t, n, diff, mindiff;
    cin >> t;
    cin >> n;
    int val[n];

    while(t--)
    {
        mindiff = 1000000000;
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            cin >> val[i];
        }
        int a = 0;
        for(a = 0; a<n ; a++)
        {
            for(int b=a+1; b<n ; b++)
            {
                diff = abs(val[a] - val[b]);
                if(diff <= mindiff)
                {
                    mindiff = diff;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << mindiff << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The results are as expected (for at least the tests I did) buts the website says its wrong.

Comment: I don't know about the results, but this `int val[n];` is wrong.

Comment: Why does it say it's wrong? Perhaps it's struggling with `int val[n];`, because that's not actually C++.

Comment: What if the list contains [1000000001, 1000000002, 1000000010] ? Your output will be wrong

Comment: `int val[n];` -- Please use `std::vector<int> val(n);` and not this invalid C++ syntax.  If `n` is large, stuff like `int val[n]` can blow out the stack memory.

Comment: online judge types of programs usually provide naive examples and then test your ability to predict and handle extreme edge cases

Comment: Have you tried putting your numbers in a `std::vector` and use a STL algorithm ? Such as `std::min_element()` ?

Comment: You need new `n` for each test case. Currently you are using the same `n` for all tests.

Comment: website shows your answer is accepted though https://www.codechef.com/status/HORSES, so what's the problem?

Comment: Use C++. `std::sort`, and then `std::adjacent_find`.  Basically two lines of C++ code to solve this.  Also, if you're going to post questions like this from an online judge site, please don't simply post the code verbatim.  No one is going to sit and type in the test cases over and over again trying to solve your problem.  Rewrite your program so that the data is hard-coded into the program.

Comment: Also, if the number is 5000, your loop is going through 5000 x 5000 iterations.  That is not a good solution.  Sorting the data (use `std::sort`), and then linearly going through it finding the pair that is the closest is much better algorithmically.

Comment: @DimChtz Array is declared as ```type arrayName [ arraySize ];```. I am confused.

Comment: @Killian I have not learned ```std::vector``` yet, gonna learn that and try again.

Comment: @ManavendraSen -- *Array is declared as type arrayName [ arraySize ]* -- No.  In C++, arrays must have their sizes denoted by *constants*, not variables.   Variable size arrays are accomplished in C++ by using `std::vector`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie@DimChtz ooh I didn't know that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things in your code that you should change:

**Use `std::vector<int>` and not variable-length arrays (VLA's)**:

Reasons:

1. Variable length arrays are not standard C++. A `std::vector` is standard C++.
2. Variable length arrays may exhaust stack memory if the number of entries is large. A `std::vector` gets its memory from the heap, not the stack.
3. Variable length arrays suffer from the same problem as regular arrays -- going beyond the bounds of the array leads to undefined
   behavior.  A `std::array` has an `at()` function that can check boundary access when desired.

---

**Use the maximum `int` to get the maximum integer value.**

Instead of

```
mindif = 1000000000;
```

it should be:

```
   #include <climits>
   //...
   int mindiff = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

---

As to the solution you chose, the comments in the main section about the nested loop should be addressed.

Instead of a nested `for` loop, you should sort the data first.  Thus finding the minimum value between two values is much easier and with less time complexity.

The program can look something like this (using the data provided at the link):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   int n = 5;
   std::vector<int> val = {4, 9, 1, 32, 13};
   int mindiff = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
   std::sort(val.begin(), val.end());
   for(int a = 0; a < n-1 ; a++)
       mindiff = std::min(val[a+1] - val[a], mindiff);
   std::cout << mindiff;           
}
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use a simple for():

```
// you already have an array called "arr" which contains some numbers.
int biggestNumber = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    if (arr[i] > biggestNumber) {
        biggestNumber = arr[i];
    }
}
```

arr.size will get the array's length so that you can check every value from the position 0 to the last one which is arr.size() - 1 (because arrays are 0 based in c++).

Hope this helps.